# Change basic colors in a ZK theme

Tags: eclipse, less, zk

I am trying to change the basic color in altantic theme (blue by default). I am new to less. I tried to change colors and build jar in eclipse using the source from github. But unable to build the project into eclipse without errors. Can someone please provide me a tutorial on how to build the theme with different colors.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simpel

You can use [the online themeroller](http://www.zkoss.org/zkthemeroller/) from zk, create it online and download your theme, but that's not for atlantic.

I downloaded the atlantic theme today and saw that you need an EE license if you want to build this.
zkmax-7.0.1 is an EE jar and that is one of your dependencies.

Comment: but using online themeroller we cannot change layouts of elements.. like we cannot make a normal button look like a button in zk atlantic theme